# accessing localhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, localhost

i had installed WAMP and registered a domain to link my website and hav resolved the dynamic ip issue which is assigned by of WAN interface. Now web ever i write my registered domain e.g: www.myweb.com , it open my DSL modem authentication page. what should i do to redirect my domain to my localhost which is served by apache webserver abd PHP(already installed and workin locally) ??

Comment: Can you clarify? You want others outside your modem to go through the dynamic ip and load your site, but if you are internal you want it just to load the localhost? Also internal to your pc? Or from any machine on your network?

Comment: You need to configure your router to send all data for that domain to your local machine.

Comment: in addition to what the others said, if you can get at your modem's authentication page from outside your network, your setup is very insecure...

Answer (score 1):

Internet visitors from outside your network can't get to your WAMP server unless you specifically configure your router (this is a good security feature). You need to setup [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/) (ideally on port 80) on your DSL router so the rest of us can access your internal server.

What manufacturer/model is your DSL router? If you find my link, and Googling, to be sucky we can help you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set auto connect behavior of your dsl modem with your credential.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web administration for your router is on port 80. You should be able to change this in your router settings somewhere.

After you have done this, set up port forwarding in your router to forward port 80 to your computer's local IP address (probably a 192.168.x.x ip).

If your computer does not have a static ip on your LAN, you can set one up in your router by enabling dhcp and assigning one to your computer's MAC address.

To find out the above addresses, you can use 'ipconfig /all' in cmd prompt.