# How to enable access to LAN?

Tags: local-area-network, localhost

I don't have a domain name.

And I browse my site by "http://localhost"

How to enable visit my site by guys not in LAN?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/54443/accessing-localhost

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** If you don't want to purchase a domain use a free service such as [NoIP](http://www.no-ip.com/) or [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/). If you can purchase a domain, you can use the free service [EveryDNS](http://www.everydns.com/) to link up your IP address (I will assume it is dynamic) with a hostname on your domain.

**Step 2:** Forward the port at your router to your machine (server). If you want web access, forward port 80 to the IP address your local machine is on (you will have to check the network settings, and also be sure that this IP address doesn't change). But, be forewarned that some ISPs block port 80 as running a web server on a residential connection is a violation of their Terms of Service.

*Note that running a server bypasses your firewall and allows outside folks (and hackers) possible access to your machine. Do not choose to do this lightly, and make sure your software and web server are constantly updated with the latest security patches.*

Answer (score 1):

You should give out your IP address to your clients.
Then they can access ypur site using URL: http://x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x is your IP.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can sign up to a dynamic DNS service provider such as *dyndns.org* service. This will allow your machine to have a user-readable domain name (xxx.dyndns.org) that you can give to people outside your LAN.

Then, you need to ensure that your Internet gateway/router/firewall is configured to forward port 80 (http) port connections into your web-server machine.

Answer (score 0):

What type of IP do you have? Static or dynamic? If you want to allow access from the internet, you will have to forward the particular port (example 80) from your router to the computer that hosts the website.